# Applying css to only Numbers in a jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

```
    var START_DATE = new Date("July 7, 2015 07:00:00");
    var INTERVAL = 20;
    var INCREMENT = 1; 
    var START_VALUE = 2824327;
    var count=2824327;
    console.log(count.toLocaleString('en-US'))
    window.onload = function()
    {
    var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
    var now = new Date();
    count = parseInt((now - START_DATE) / msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
   document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count.toLocaleString('en-US');
   setInterval(function() {
   count += INCREMENT;
   document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count.toLocaleString('en-US');
   }, msInterval);
   }
```

I want to apply bellow css to numbers only

```
.number {
font-family: Verdana;
color: white;
background: black;
}
```

The jQuery am suppose to add to my other jQuery is bellow

```
$('p').html(function(i, v){
    return v.replace(/(\d)/g, '<span class="number">$1</span>');
});
```

Help me on how am suppose to achieve this.

Comment: put the numbers in a seperate div with a seprate class and apply the above css to that class, anyway, it's better if you elaborate a bit more on what you need if this doesnt solve the answer.

Comment: if it was a static number could have just put in a div but now the numbers are changing are being generated by jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Change script to

```
 var START_DATE = new Date("July 7, 2015 07:00:00");
    var INTERVAL = 20;
    var INCREMENT = 1; 
    var START_VALUE = 2824327;
    var count=2824327;
    console.log(count.toLocaleString('en-US'))
    window.onload = function()
    {
    var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
    var now = new Date();
    count = parseInt((now - START_DATE) / msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
   document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count.toLocaleString('en-US');
   $('p').html(function(i, v){
        return v.replace(/(\d)/g, '<span class="number">$1</span>');
    });
   setInterval(function() {
   count += INCREMENT;
   document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count.toLocaleString('en-US');
   $('p').html(function(i, v){
        return v.replace(/(\d)/g, '<span class="number">$1</span>');
    });
   }, msInterval);
   }
```

dont want jQuery code

Comment: the code is not working, this one also cause the number not to auto update only updates on page reload